# Unit Tests for controller with DB action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, automated-tests

I have a question, how should I test this method, which has db action in it, with a unit test?

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Category category = db.Category.Find(id);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View("Details", category);
    }
```

Comment: That action should be refactored to not be tightly coupled to implementation concerns. Controller actions should be kept as lean as possible. extract the db context out behind an abstraction and explicitly inject it into the controller via constructor injection. That explicit dependency would now be easier to mock when testing the action in isolation.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how should I inject the entities to each controller and where should I create the entities object?

Comment: Read up on dependency inversion principle as it relates to Asp. MVC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Comment: Personally I would recommend you to read a book: 'The Art of Unit Testing: with Examples in .NET ' by Roy Osherove. This books could uncover a lot of interesting information for you. Especially relationship between abstraction and good unit tests.